# How to write an anonymous class version of this?

Tags: java

Is it possible to define the MyComponent class as an anonymous class inside the argument list of frame.add() method? How?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
        frame.setSize(750,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new MyComponent());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class MyComponent extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.drawString("Hello", 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, depending on what you want you can use

```
frame.add(new JComponent() {//anonymous class will extend JComponent 
                            //in same way MyComponent does
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.drawString("Hello", 100, 100);
    }
});
```

or

```
frame.add(new MyComponent(){//anonymous class which will extend MyComponent
    //you can add more code/members here 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason why I got confused was because we are required to create an instance of `MyComponent` but looks like you are creating an instance of the `JComponent` class inside the arguments?

Comment: Yes, in first example I am creating anonymous class which will extend `JComponent` in a same way `MyComponent` does, so it will act similar as `MyComponent` instance. But if you need anonymous class which will need to extend `MyComponent` you can also do it same way as shown in first example (add `{..}` block after calling constructor).

Comment: Also, while we're at it, let me get something else clarified as well. Is the syntax the same for creating an anonymous class of a class that implements an interface?

Comment: Cheers mate. Sorry. My bad.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean, but lets say that in `new SomeType(){...}` you can put as `SomeType` any non-final type you want, it can be class or interface.

Comment: Just to be clear again, both the versions of your code are absolutely equivalent for all practical purposes, right?

Comment: What I mean in my second question is  how do you create an anonymous class like you did had MyComponent `implemented` JComponent (just assume it did, even though it can't) instead of extending it?

Comment: Also, buddy, when I tried to run the program, the second version doesn't work. I believe it's because we haven't defined the MyComponent class.

Comment: "both the versions of your code are absolutely equivalent for all practical purposes" Yes, except being type equivalent (JComponent will not be instance of MyComponent) they will act the same as long as you will provide same changes for `JComponent` as you did for `MyComponent` which is overriding `paintComponent` methods.

Comment: "how do you create an anonymous class like you did had MyComponent implemented JComponent" It is same way. Lets take an example where we will try to add anonymous class which will `implement ActionListener` (which is interface): http://pastebin.com/gE9qCfev

Comment: "Also, buddy, when I tried to run the program, the second version doesn't work." strange, it works fine for me. Are you sure that you didn't change anything?

Comment: Pshemo, I just can't thank you enough. I learnt something new today. :) Respect man. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Just add the method inside the body of the anonymous class:

```
frame.add(new JComponent() {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.drawString("Hello", 100, 100);
    }
});
```

Comment: Cheers mate. Appreciate. :)